# How to reorder JS Object based on partial key value match

Tags: javascript, object

I have the following Object in JS:

```
var obj = {
  elem_1: "el1",
  elem_2: "el2",
  elem_3: "el3",
  exp_1: "ex1",
  exp_2: "ex2",
  exp_3: "ex3"
};
```

I am trying to reorder it so each `elem_#` is followed by `exp_#`.

I started the following code but not sure how I can achieve it:

```
obj.sort(function (index, data) { 
    return data.key.split('_')[1] == '1' ? 2 : data.key == '2' ? 1 : 0 
});
```

How can I achieve what I am looking to do.

Comment: You would have to remove the properties and readd them to the object to preserve the order. If order matters, use a structure that supports it, like an array.

Comment: Unfortunately I can only use an object. I tried converting an array to object everything went out of place.

Comment: You can't sort an object, use an array of objects, maybe

Comment: Keep this in mind: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the keys by doing `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`, `split()` them, and then `.sort()` them.

I then use `.reduce()` to turn them back into an object. Reduce iterates through all values of an array to produce a single output. In this case, the output is `acc` (short for "accumulator") - with each iteration, I add our property to `acc` by taking the existing contents (`...acc`) and combining it with our new property (`[item]: obj[item]`). The `...acc` syntax is making use of [spread syntax for object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals). The second parameter (just `{}` in the example below) is the initial value of `acc`.

It's important to note that property order in objects has only recently become guaranteed in JavaScript (ES2015+, *non-integer* property names only). Personally, I still consider relying on their order to be a slight smell.

```js
var obj = {
  elem_1: "el1",
  elem_2: "el2",
  elem_3: "el3",
  exp_1: "ex1",
  exp_2: "ex2",
  exp_3: "ex3"
};

var res = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)
  .sort((a,b) => a.split("_")[1] - b.split("_")[1])
  .reduce((acc,item) => ({...acc, [item]: obj[item]}), {});
  
console.log(res);
```

**EDIT:** Per [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30076219/does-es6-introduce-a-well-defined-order-of-enumeration-for-object-properties) (mentioned by wlh in a comment above), if dealing with property order, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` is a better choice than `Object.keys()`.

Comment: What is `...acc`?

Comment: Good question. I'll add some detail to my answer to explain a bit more in-depth.

Comment: @Si8 this will help regarding `...acc`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Comment: ahhhhhh makes sense now... Thanks for the link and also clarification

Comment: @Si8 I've clarified in my answer :)

Comment: also I didn't see the `acc` as the parameter... silly me! Now it makes sense. Thanks

Comment: hey I for some reason had to not use `.reduce()` and it worked fine.

Comment: In the example above, removing the `reduce()` step would output an array of sorted property names. If that's sufficient output then you can lose the `reduce()` portion - that step is only necessary for converting it back into an object (and including the values). If the `reduce` step *isn't working*, it may be that you're using an older browser that doesn't yet support the object spread syntax.

Comment: so I just tested it and it shows up fine collapsed but when i expand it, it goes back to the old way

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "collapse" and "expand".

Comment: Nevermind, ES6 that's why it's not working. only upto ES5 unfortunately... I think this code is working correctly

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this

Take the keys and `sort` them and than `map` back get the objects in desired form.

```js
var obj = {
  elem_1: "el1",
  elem_2: "el2",
  elem_3: "el3",
  exp_1: "ex1",
  exp_2: "ex2",
  exp_3: "ex3"
};

let op = Object.keys(obj)
        .sort((a,b)=> a.split('_')[1] - b.split('_')[1])
        .map(e=> ({[e]: obj[e]}) )

console.log(op)
```

P.S :- This is assumes that your input will always in the defined form as of your example.

Comment: Thanks. Yes it will always end if a number. However it will fail let's say the number is  in the double digit... I think a `split` as mentioned by Tyler is better example for the failesafe

Answer (score 0):

What about

```js
var obj = {
  elem_1: "el1",
  elem_2: "el2",
  elem_3: "el3",
  exp_1: "ex1",
  exp_2: "ex2",
  exp_3: "ex3"
}

obj = Object.entries(obj).sort((a, b) => a[0].split('_')[1]-b[0].split('_')[1])
.map(([key, val]) => ([key, val]))
.reduce((obj, [k, v]) => Object.assign(obj, { [k]: v }), {})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could split the keys and sort by number and string in the wanted order by taking an object for the order. Later rebuild a new object.

```js
var object = { elem_1: "el1", elem_2: "el2", elem_3: "el3", exp_1: "ex1", exp_2: "ex2", exp_3: "ex3" },
    order = { elem: 1, exp: 2 };

object = Object.assign(...Object
    .entries(object)
    .sort(([a], [b]) => {
        var aa = a.split('_'),
            bb = b.split('_');
        return aa[1] - bb[1] || order[aa[0]] - order[bb[0]];
    })
    .map(([k, v]) => ({ [k]: v }))
);

console.log(object);
```